# Django: MultipleChoiceFilter on Model TextChoices

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a Model which holds `models.TextChoices`.

```py
class Visit(BaseModel):
    class VisitStatus(models.TextChoices):
        INQUIRED = 'INQ', _('Inquired')
        OPTIONAL = 'OPT', _('Optional')
        CONFIRMED = 'CON', _('Confirmed')
        ACTIVE = 'ACT', _('Active')
        INACTIVE = 'INA', _('Inactive')
        CANCELLED = 'CXL', _('Cancelled')
```

I am trying to use the `MultipleChoiceFilter` from `django-filter` as follows:

```py
    class VisitFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        status = django_filters.filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=models.Visit.VisitStatus, empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Visit
        fields = ['status']
```

I keep getting the following TypeError

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the choices attribute of the enum class i.e  `models.Visit.VisitStatus.choices` so use :

```
status = django_filters.filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=models.Visit.VisitStatus.choices, empty_label=None)
```